# Overriding Method in WPF ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, overloading

I have a `BaseFormViewModel` class which some of ViewModels inherit from. It inherits from another base class called `BaseViewModel` which just contains implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

The `BaseFormViewModel` contains several methods which I intend to be `overriden` in the derived classes:

```
public class BaseFormViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public BaseFormViewModel() {
            _InitiateParameterAnswer = new Command(param => RaiseInitiateParameterAnswer(param));
        }

        protected Command _InitiateParameterAnswer;
        public Command InitiateParameterAnswer {
            get {
                return _InitiateParameterAnswer;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void RaiseInitiateParameterAnswer(object values) {
            //Implementation
        }

        protected virtual Parameter SetAuditParameter(ParameterOption parameterOption, Guid parameterId, string remarks, string description, int weight) {
            //Implementation

        }
}
```

Here's one of the derived classes:

```
public class FSCGeneralProductionProcessMainViewModel : BaseFormViewModel {

    public FSCGeneralProductionProcessMainViewModel() {

    }

    protected override void RaiseInitiateParameterAnswer(object values) {
        //Implementation
    }

    protected override Parameter SetAuditParameter(ParameterOption parameterOption, Guid parameterId, string remarks, string description, int weight) {
        //Implementation
    }
```

However, whenever I invoke the `InitiateParameterAnswer` Command, the base class methods are being called. What am I missing here?

UPDATE: 
Thanks for the feedbacks. With @Muds comment, I realised that I am calling each form (View) via Reflection and downcasting its DataContext (ViewModel) to `BaseFormViewModel`:

```
//Create an instance of the corresponding form using reflection
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formName, true));

//Set the FormId
var viewModel       = ((UserControl)instance).DataContext as BaseFormViewModel;
viewModel.FormId    = formId;
viewModel..AuditId  = auditId;
```

(The reason I have to is to set the value of base properties FormId and AuditId as illustrated above).

UPDATE 2:
The `Command` class is implemented as follows:

```
public class Command : ICommand {

    public Command(Action action, bool canExecute = true) {
        this.action = action;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    //ICommand Interface implementation here
}
```

UPDATE 3:

I instantiate the ViewModel inside the Form's constructor:

```
public partial class FSCStationProductionProcessMainView : UserControl {

    public FSCStationProductionProcessMainView () {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    private void InitializeViewModel () {
        this.DataContext = new FSCStationProductionProcessMainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you casting your object to base ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour from the code you've shown. How is your Command class implemented?

Comment: Only the base class method is calling? Do you have something like base.RaiseInitiateParameterAnswer in your implementation of `FSCGeneralProductionProcessMainViewModel`?

Comment: Obviously something hides your derived implementation. Either a cast or an explicit base class call. Please show more code. The part where the method is called and the part where those derived viewmodels are stored will suffice.

Comment: @Clemens updated the question with my `Command` class. Basically, it's just a straightforward implementation of `ICommand` interface.

Comment: I do not believe that you can hide an overridden method by performing a base class cast before calling. The whole point of a virtual method is that you call through a base class reference but the indirection of the virtual method call ensures that the overridden method is called.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer would be to mark your BaseFormViewModel  RaiseInitiateParameterAnswer method implementation as 'abstract' and force all derived classes to provide an implementation.

But in general this design seems overly complex:

Do you really need to so many levels of inheritence - it will be confusing and difficult in the long term to support and maintain.

Inheritence in my opinion should be used sparingly in object orientiated design.

Comment: that's what virtual methods are for, so that all bases classes are not forced to have common implementation.. I don't think marking abstract is a solution

Comment: The `BaseViewModel` is the base class for all ViewModels in my application. The `BaseFormVIewModel` is for all the "Forms". It has a distinct functionality that are only specific to "Forms".

Marking the method abstract would result to duplicating codes on the derived class which I was hoping to avoid.